# Way to execute Google Standalone Script directly from Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

Well, I've been reading the documentation for a long time but, as per usual, it's really unclear...

I'm developing a Google Script with the Script Editor that is already working as expected (it have nothing to see with any G suite program but with Drive).

By now, the only way to execute it is opening the script editor and press on the "play" button or the "execute" bar and press on the function.

Obviously this is not a solution since anyone from the bussines could modify/see the code.

So the question is this: **how can I make from this script something like an "exe" that I just have to double ckick (its obviously located at Drive) and it executes the script?**

I saw [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) but seems it says no way to do it except from opening the code and execute from the google app script editor...

Comment: what you are asking is not possible, but there are some ways to do similar to that. so, could you tell us what you are actually doing with the app script?

Comment: ufff... Really sad that it's not posible...  When I readed about "standalone Scripts" I though it was the heaven... The script just gets the last document in a folder that is supposed to be a csv (but its semicolon separated) and parses it to make it comma separated. Then deletes all the documents but this last one. That's why I dont need to use the script with Spreadsheets, docs or anything but Drive and it's very dissapointing that can't do that...

Comment: you can set triggers to do that. see that here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: I already read about it but I dont know how should I append that to my script since I dont need any G Suite program like Sheets or anything... And by the way, the document to be edited by the Script always changes so triggers might be installed every time

Comment: if you need to execute app script function instantly on demand, then you have to enter the app script console and execute the function manually. It's the only way. But, if you are ok to fire the app script function on time based(say every 5hrs) you can do that! here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) under **Managing triggers programmatically** section

Comment: This would be the solution if I could make a trigger for Drive with something like: onCreateDocument, but can't even create a trigger for Drive at all... Thanks a lot anyway and maybe I'll try the Web solution since Google does not provide many optimal choices...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159231/discussion-between-srimadhan11-and-alejandro93sa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Web App is triggered by either an HTTPS GET or POST request.  You don't need to use Google Drive.

Ways to trigger a Web App:

- Chrome Extension - You can create a Chrome Extension to make an HTTPS GET or POST request.  The user would need to install the Chrome extension, and the Chrome extension could put a button in the browser.
- Link - Some HTML with a link in it.  An email with a link in it.  Click the link.
- Address Bar - Browser's address bar - Every browser's address bar issues an HTTPS GET request, so you can run a Web App directly from the address bar.  Put the published Web App url into the browser address bar and click whatever the browser uses to load the page. (Only for a GET request)
- Bookmark - The user could bookmark the link to your Web App. So, they would need to click the link in their bookmark.
- Any program that can make an HTTPS GET or POST request.  For example, make a POST request from Python or C++.

For a GET request, you need a `doGet()` function in your script, and to react to a POST request you need a `doPost()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that posible ways to do it. The point here is that it's very sad that Google haven't provided a way to directly create scripts that execute on Drive that would let you do interesting things like delete old documents, parse documents like i'm trying and a long etc. Finally I'm trying to do it with a Google Form that when you press on submit, it executes the script I made (I'm on it since I'm really new on Google Scripts for G Suite). By the way, Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your requirements the only way would be to deploy your script as a web app with a minimal user interface, just a short message to confirm proper execution for example.

You will never have a "local" executable file since everything in Apps Script is done on google's servers, not in our computers. Instead you will have an url... (with the advantage that it is completely OS independent ! )

The script will remain private unless you share it and you'll be able to choose who can use that url.

Comment: Could I create a button for Google Drive that I could press and execute a function this way? (like an "exe" file but with a button being a web app)

Comment: Mmmm, I don't think so, I'm not aware of the possible customizations in drive, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

1. Build the menu first.
2. Click "Run My Code".
3. Click the "Run My Code" button.

runmycode.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function runMyCode()
    {
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(updateMyDiv)
         .myFunctionName();
    }
    function updateMyDiv(hl)
    {
      document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML+='<br />'+ hl;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" value="Run My Code" onclick="runMyCode()" />
   <div id="MyDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

runMyCode.gs:

```
function myFunctionName() {
  return "Your function has run";
}

function startYourSideBar()
{
   var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('runmycode');
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function buildMenu()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Run My Code') 
     .addItem('Run My Code', 'startYourSideBar')
     .addToUi()
}
```